# Hard disk almost full

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, disk-usage

I installed Ubuntu a while ago on my computer and despite having done some preliminary researches I am encountering a hard disk space problem. Ultimately I think I understood that partitioning my hard disk so as to install Ubuntu on a 20 Gb partition would be more than OK and would be  even common practice but as I installed other softwares, this hard disk is now getting almost full and I am wondering if I misunderstood something:

Are the softwares not meant to be installed on this hard disk? 
For instance, I installed Cuda and this software takes up to 4.3Gb alone. 
I don't understand why I had read so many times that 20 Gb would be ok if by installing just a couple of software it is getting full so easily.

I'm not sure if my problem is clear enough, please do tell me if you need any further info. I have to admit I am feeling a little lost here and am wondering if I should re-install and reconfigure my entire machine to solve the problem :/

many thanks in advance for your help!

[Insights from my disk usage analyser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRudU.png) (1)

[Insights from my disk usage analyser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HYak.png) (2)

NB: here is the output from df -h

```
me@comp:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           774M   18M  757M   3% /run
/dev/sda5        19G   16G  1,6G  92% /
tmpfs           3,8G  882M  3,0G  23% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6       231G  141G   90G  62% /home
tmpfs           774M   76K  774M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb        230G  174G   44G  80% /media/me/DATA
```

Comment: I think you may have read a recommendation for the space needed for a Virtual Machine. 20G is plenty for trying out a distribution but obviously if you start adding 4G packages that 20G will soon be used up. Looks like you can solve your issue by reducing sda6 a bit and expanding sda5. You need to boot an install disk/usb and use GParted to do this.

Comment: I don't understand why you believed that 20GB would be adequate either. Re-installing with a more realistic partitioning scheme is what you will eventually wind up doing anyway, so may as well do it sooner instead of later. Lots of folks flirt with many-partition schemes with a tiny '/' partition, and lots of folks tend to run out of space because of it.

Comment: Quite a few people suggest creating a 20GB root partition, and yes, it is a bad advice. Why they do it, I don't really know.

Comment: @PonJar I ended up doing exactly what you recommended namely extending my partition size with Gparted. Using Gparted was quite easy with the GUI. I know have 45Gb instead of 20, I think this should be sufficient. :-)

Comment: It’s really nice to hear that my suggestion helped

Answer (score 0):

*Are the softwares not meant to be installed on this hard disk?* They are meant to be installed, but they do take up space when you install them. This is a universal issue across all computers and operating systems; as drives get cheaper and bigger, software developers write bigger code.

*I don't understand why I had read so many times that 20 Gb would be ok if by installing just a couple of software it is getting full so easily.* Those folks were talking about typical users; your use of CUDA puts you in a minority of Linux users, 'power users'. It's reasonable to expect folks who use powerful software will need more room to work in.

A simple solution would be to add another drive, and to put /home on it, moving it from /dev/sda . If you provide the make and model of the PC (from the serial number sticker on the bottom or back), http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com could recommend expansion options.

For example, I was able to add an eMMC drive inside my Lenovo Thinkpad T420 without removing the original drive and the expansion drive, and with two SSDs and the eMMC, have plenty of room for media as well as two operating systems and many apps for each.